# HP5440 'Envy' Printer won't print, is 'turned off' according to troubleshooter

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, printer, hp-envy

My HP5440 'Envy' Printer with my laptop running on Windows 10 won't print. When I run the troubleshooter (via Devices and Settings) it informs me erroneously that the printer is turned off. The printer is in fact on, and successfully connected to Wi-fi, as is my laptop.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Turn off the wireless router and turn it on again
2. Turn off the printer and turn it on again
3. Restart the laptop

The printer queue will then immediately start to clear.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the HP Smart Print app is installed (Microsoft Store).

Uninstall the HP Program (Control Panel, Programs and Features).

Restart the computer.

Now in Control Panel, Devices and Printers, install the printer. This should install it and you can test it. Windows has most Printer Drivers.

Once running, you can use HP Smart Print to manage it.